# Apache forward JSP pages to Tomcat?

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, jsp

I have an Apache Server, in which my website running. But there are some JSP pages in my website. I have to forward my JSP pages and servlet to Tomcat.

How can I make that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to use [**mod_proxy_ajp**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_ajp.html) for your purpose.

```
 (Internet)---[Apache]---ajp---[Tomcat]---(JSP)
```

There are many examples on how to do this and most Linux distributions would come with some standard configuration files to help you get started.

Comment: can you give me some explanation, I have wamp 5, tomcat 6.0. I am using window OS.